# How to organize JSON for faster info access?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been experimenting with storing Vehicle info as JSON for a quicker way to access the vehicle images.

I have set up a table in my DB for JSON. The JSON is set up as shown below. All the vehicles are in this one JSON, along with all their image information. I'm not sure if this is the best way of storing the data. I want to be able to quickly search based on the VIN to get only the images associated with that VIN.

My Issues:

1. The loading speed of dynamically displaying associated vehicle images.
2. Not getting ONLY the associated images; other vehicle images are showing
3. Not sure if my JSON format makes sense (or is inefficient), haven't worked too much with JSON
4. Is there an easier way to set up the SQL table for querying a specific JSON?

Possible Solutions (not limited to one):

- Re-format JSON for simple referencing
- Re-format Table for easier queries
- Edit "code loops" for faster run time

I had previously set up loops on the InventoryPage, this is a dynamic page that uses $_GET to get the associated VIN, to iterate through my Database to get the images associated with the VIN. This worked, but took too long due to the amount of iterations required.

There are usually much more entries than this, I trimmed it way back for easier readability. We have an average of 100 vehicles with 20-60 images per vehicle.
Here is an example of my JSON format:

```
[{"vin": "JF1GR89658L827860", "images": [{"image": 
"https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/23594569/1133776572.jpg?
dt=100320180034", "width": 800, "height": 600}, {"image": 
"https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/23594569/1133776606.jpg?
dt=100320180034", "width": 800, "height": 600}]}, 
{"vin": "6Y86G433753", "images": [{"image": 
"https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/23684711/1135715340.jpg?
dt=100620180134", "width": 800, "height": 600}, {"image": 
"https://cdn04.carsforsale.com/3/420970/23684711/1135715371.jpg?
dt=100620180134", "width": 800, "height": 600}]}]
```

The code I currently have to iterate through the JSON and find the associated images, which I think incorrectly displays images from different vehicles:

```
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle)
        {
            if ($vehicle['vin'] === $vin) {

                $last_element = ',';



                while ($vehicle['images']) {
                    echo "{";
                    echo "src: '" . $vehicle['images'][0]['image'] . "',";
                    echo "h: " . $vehicle['images'][0]['height'] . ",";
                    echo "w: " . $vehicle['images'][0]['width'];
                    echo "}" . $last_element;


                } 

                break;
            }
        }
```

Expected output from above "code loops" (for image slider):

```
{
  src: "image_link",
  h: vehicle_height,
  w: vehicle_width
}
```

Comment: `$vehicle['vin'] = $vin` is assigning the value, `==` is to test it.

Comment: Good eye, changing that right now, testing, then editing question ASAP.

Comment: In my opinion, using SQL JSON functions is a real pain. Stick with normal database normalization. Many things that are easy to do with joins become tricky with JSON.

Comment: For instance, I don't think there's anything analogous to `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for JSON components.

Comment: I was using a normal database setup, but couldn't figure out how to speed up my load times; too many dynamic things going on. After researching JSON, I thought it might be able to help with this specific situation. I don't plan on using JSON for anything other than the images, meaning it probably wouldn't use joins?

Comment: Also not sure what your doing with the loop `while ($vehicle['images'])` is it will not stop (unless you have an error).

Comment: I think he meant `if ($vehicle['images'])`

Comment: @NigelRen I guess I was attacking it as I would a normal DB queried set of info; which I take is not the case with this JSON example? As in trying to get all the images within the IMAGES

Comment: Without getting into JSON in databases, you could speed up getting items from your JSON considerably if you indexed it by VIN.

Comment: Actually, `foreach ($vehicle['images'] as $image)`

Comment: Don't create JSON by hand. Use `echo json_encode(['src' => $image['image'], 'h' => $image['height'], 'w' => $image['width']]);`

Comment: @Don'tPanic So I have a few tables; this one is my only JSON table. My regular "vehicles" table is set up with the VIN as Primary Key and another "vehicle_images" table with Foreign Key as VIN

Comment: I'm saying, you might think of accessing the JSON in the same way you'd think of querying normal DB tables. So instead of an array of objects with vin properties, like `[{"vin": "JF1GR89658L827860", "images": [...`, an object with properties named by vin, like `{"JF1GR89658L827860": {"images": [...`. That way you don't have to iterate the whole thing, you can just directly access the one vin you're looking for. Not sure how you're creating the JSON that goes in that table, though, so it may not be feasible to do it that way.

Comment: Why are you putting all the vehicles in a single JSON array? Shouldn't each vehivle be a separate row in the table, with the array of images in the JSON column?

Comment: @Barmar I thought so too, that's how I have my other tables set up. I'm still relatively new to JSON and wasn't sure how to query JSON; so I thought I would try it this way for now. I definitely would rather have it be separated into rows.

Comment: Oh, I had assumed there were multiple rows, each with a set of vehicles associated with it. Is there just one row with all the JSON?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ahh my bad. There is just one row with all the JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to create JSON by hand. Construct an array with all the data, then call `json_encode()`.

```
$json_array = array();
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle)
{
    if ($vehicle['vin'] = $vin) {
        foreach ($vehicle['images'] as $image) {
            $json_array[] = ['src' => $image['image'], 'h' => $image['height'], 'w' => $image['width']];
        } 
        break;
    }
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

You might also consider making the JSON column an object rather than an array, with `vin` as the keys. Then you wouldn't need a loop, you could just use `$vehicle[$vin]`. You could also use `JSON_SEARCH()` in your MySQL query to just extract that element instead of the whole array.

Comment: lol, I was going to delete my question since it's essentially the same as yours, then I saw you already deleted yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an opinionated answer, but I really don't see the benefit of using a JSON column for this. I think it looks like the data you have is a better fit for traditional related tables. I think JSON columns are great for storing more unstructured data, sets of different objects with different properties. But you have a set of similar objects, each a flat list with exactly the same properties. Image records would fit perfectly in their own table, possibly with a relationship to a different table with other VIN-related data, and I think retrieving related data would be simpler and more efficient that way. Just my two cents, and I know it doesn't really answer the question directly, but it's a bit much for a comment.